# iframe with a php form not working in IE

Tags: php, forms, internet-explorer, iframe

I updated the info so you can get a better understanding:

I have an iframe with a PHP form when the user submits the form in IE it does not seem to post the data. It works in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE 7, 8 and 10.

What is happening is when we test the iframe php form on our server in IE, Firefox, Chrome and Safari it works fine but when the client uploads the code to their server and test it doesn't work for them on IE. The weird thing is I can test the iframe php form on their server it works fine on all the browsers using Windows 7 and XP. The client is testing the iframe php code in IE7, 8, 10 on Windows 7 and XP.

One more important thing to know. The iframe html page is still being hosted on our server since the client doesn't use php on their server.

Here is the iframe tag

```
<iframe id="iframe" frameborder="0" src="FullURL/reportBuilderForm.html"></iframe>
```

Here is the iframe code:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="ie7" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="ie8" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Website</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body id="reportForm">
<div class="row">
    <form  onsubmit="" name="report_form" id="report_form" action="generatePDF.php" method="POST" target="_blank">

    <div class="sixcol">
        <label class="blue">
            <input type="checkbox" name="leadership" id="leadership" class="noMargin"/>
            Leadership &mdash; Chairman's Messages</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label class="blue">
            <input type="checkbox" name="company" id="company" class="noMargin"/>
            Company</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label class="blue">
            <input type="checkbox" name="performance" id="performance" class="noMargin"/>
            Performance</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label class="blue">
            <input type="checkbox" name="solutions" id="solutions" class="noMargin"/>
            Solutions</label>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="sixcol last">
        <label class="blue">
            <input type="checkbox" name="relationships" id="relationships" class="noMargin"/>
            Relationships</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label class="blue">
            <input type="checkbox" name="culture" id="culture" class="noMargin"/>
            Culture</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label class="blue">
            <input type="checkbox" name="responsibility" id="responsibility" class="noMargin"/>
            Responsibility</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label class="blue">
            <input type="checkbox" name="leadershipBoard" id="leadershipBoard" class="noMargin"/>
            Leadership &mdash; Board &amp; Sr. Management</label>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <hr />
    <input name="generateReportBtn" class="generateBtn" type="submit" tabindex="4" value="generate PDF" id="submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One does not simply create a website that works with Internet Explorer

Comment: One does not simply create a sentence that implies Internet Explorer works, has ever worked, or ever will "work".

Comment: Can you please include the top part of the form declaration? Also, if you could include the iframe tag so we can see that as well. Thanks!

Comment: @Revent - I just did. I was trying to figure out why the code kept cutting off.

Comment: start with correct HTML, ie is very sensetive. 
css and js should be inside the head tag.
and try giving a better description of what is not working
BTW, are you using session or cookies ?

Comment: Why is your link tag outside of <head>?  Why is the title tag not the first tag in the <head>?  If you're going to use <hr /> then you should also use <br />. Be consistent.

Comment: First, can you please test if it works for the clients by opening the form page directly, not from the iframe. If so, then we are closer to the problem as most likely caused by the way IE handles this iframe.

Comment: The HTML is actually correct but I was in a rush and copied the HTML wrong (Don't tell me how I did that LOL). Thanks for the comments but we ended up doing a different solution. We decided to host the page with the iframe and the php form on our server.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem..... Is IE a no no for iFrame form submits where sessions are used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments but we ended up doing a different solution. We decided to host the page with the iframe and the php form on our server.